# How do you store API tokens securely?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, security, encryption, token

When user enter their API token on the browser, I need securely save their token. What is good approach to encrypt user's token?

I wax considering using AWS Secrets Manager to store User's token through API but it turn out it is really expensive. $0.40 per secret per month.

I might consider encrypting user token in the MySQL and store master secret in the `.env` file

Is there alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using AWS services it makes sense to take advantage of more resilient cloud-native solutions.

With SSM you only pay for your underlying AWS resources managed or created by AWS Systems Manager, however, parameter store *as well as the majority of other AWS services* using KMS for decryption and encryption purposes.

Additional alternatives:

- Cache SSM params for instance https://github.com/alexcasalboni/ssm-cache-python
- Use credstash (dynamodb + kms)
- Use s3 with server and client side encryption https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html

Based on your usage you will need to do the math, KMS is not free, but has a decent monthly free tier

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, you can save the token AWS DynamoDB, encrypted at rest with AWS KMS.

In addition to the Lambda charges, AWS KMS will mainly cost $1 for CMK, and based on the on-demand encryption and decryption operations about $0.03 per 10,000 requests and the free tier will give 20,000 requests/month free of charge.

For more details about pricing, refer [AWS KMS pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/pricing/) section.

Comment: What do you mean by save the token AWS DynamoDB? tokens need to be encrypted